# How to use the value in HTML dropdown "select" immediately after choosing one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to use the value in HTML dropdown "select" immediately after choosing one? Right now  to "use the month value to do some work" using the month value I have to add a button. Only after the button pressed it goes to "use the month value to do some work". Is there any easy way that immediately after choosing one value from dropdown it "use the month value to do some work"?

HTML:

```
<select id="month">
      <option value="1">Jan</option>
      <option value="2">Feb</option>
      ...
</select>
<button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function() {
    //use the month value to do some work
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `change` event:

```
$("#month").change(function() {
    // use $(this).val() to do some work
});
```